# Java Swing textfield issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jtextfield

I created a GUI using Netbeans which took asked the user to input the content in `textfields` and `textareas`. When I'm trying to use it in other classes, the text entered in the `textfield` does not appear when i use `getText` method on it. Rather in its place, the text which appears in the `textfield` specified using the edit text option in Netbeans, appears whenever `getText` method is used. Is the problem related to some sort of sequencing or order? Because I believe the text from the GUI, is being referenced before the user is actually entering it.

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public GUI() {

    initComponents();
}
public void Grow(){
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    UsernameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    PasswordLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    subject = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    SubjectLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    message = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    salutation = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    sendbutton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    password = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
    jPanel1.setBorder(new        javax.swing.border.LineBorder(java.awt.SystemColor.controlDkShadow, 3, true));

    username.setText("Enter your text here");

    UsernameLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
    UsernameLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    UsernameLabel.setText("Username");

    PasswordLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
    PasswordLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    PasswordLabel.setText("Password");

    subject.setText("Enter your text here");
    subject.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
    subject.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            subjectActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    SubjectLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
    SubjectLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    SubjectLabel.setText("Subject");

    message.setColumns(20);
    message.setRows(5);
    message.setText("Enter your text here");
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(message);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    jLabel1.setText("Message");

    salutation.setText("Enter your text here");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    jLabel2.setText("Salutation");

    sendbutton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    sendbutton.setText("Send");
    sendbutton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sendbuttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    password.setText("Enter your text here");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(SubjectLabel))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(salutation)
                        .addComponent(subject))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(UsernameLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(PasswordLabel))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(username)
                        .addComponent(password))
                    .addGap(47, 47, 47))
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(sendbutton)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(UsernameLabel)
                .addComponent(subject, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(SubjectLabel))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(PasswordLabel)
                .addComponent(salutation, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 185, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
            .addComponent(sendbutton))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


private void subjectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void sendbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    MMMMain object = new MMMMain();
    object.MassMail();

}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel PasswordLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel SubjectLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel UsernameLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
public javax.swing.JTextArea message;
public javax.swing.JPasswordField password;
public javax.swing.JTextField salutation;
public javax.swing.JButton sendbutton;
public javax.swing.JTextField subject;
public javax.swing.JTextField username;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You code seems to have little to _no_ code relevent event programming, and this _does_ seem to be a event driven problem. All I see is an empty `actionPerformed` and another `actionPerformed` with an instantiation of a class that does not exist in your code. How are we supposed to deduce _anything_ from this? It's already bad enough your question is unclear. You need to **hand code** [**a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can test it out, and do better job at explaining your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the problem related to some sort of sequencing or order? Because I
>   believe the text from the GUI, is being referenced before the user is
>   actually entering it.

Regardless your code doesn't actually recreate your problem, Swing works in an event-driven scenario. This means an event must happen if you want to get the text field's text properly. For instance:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

System.out.println(textField.getText());
```

Then nothing will be printed because the `getText()` call happens *before* the user has had even the chance to write anything. But if you do this:

```
final JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(textField.getText());
    }
};

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Then the text will be printed when user types some text and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the text field. This is because an [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) is fired and text field has attached an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) which listens to those events and does something in response. You can read more about it in [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) section of the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).